# Javascript const, let array value reassignment will update the original array?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am having a `const current = [0,1]` and push it to an array `array1.push(current)`. Then I reassign the `current` to a `let previous = current`. If I update the `previous[1] = 7`, why the `array1` value also updated?

Comment: Why would anything else happen? You're not making a copy, you only have one array.

Comment: `const` means that you can't reassign a different value to that variable. It doesn't mean that the object that variable is referring to becomes immutable.

Answer (score 0):

`previous` and `current` are referencing same array here [0,1]. so any update you make on current or previous will reflect in the current/previous reference you pushed into the array1.

if you don’t want `previous[1]=7` to change `current` array . then I suggest you do `let previous = Array.from(current)`. that way `current` won’t change even when you run `previous[1]=7` since current and previous are pointed to two different arrays( or memory spaces)

these are the keywords I look at when i get confused about this `deep copy, shallow copy`.

Answer (score -2):

Just figured by myself: the `=` just copy the reference of original array instead of the original value.